# Problem to run a bash script from within Python3 code

Tags: python, linux, bash, operating-system

I work with Linux system.

I have many different folders, each folder have a bash file (the bash file is equal in each folder). This bash file runs simple commands such as to load an environment, to create files and folders, to run binary applications (for example code1)

Out of these folders there is a python file in which I want to run
baseFolder/myPython.py
"     folder1/myBash
"     folder2/myBash
.
.
.
"     folderN/myBash

PROBLEM: when I run the Python script (for example code2) the bash file is not executed inside the `folder<i>`, it is executed as the bash file were located in the baseFoldes, hence it create folder, files, etc. within baseFolder.
I don't understand why.

I used os and subprocess packages:

```
os.system('shell command')

subprocess.run('shell command')

subprocess.call('shell command')
```

code1

```
#!/bin/bash
mkdir myNewFolder

touch myNewFile
```

code2

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import os

import subprocess

... other code ...

subprocess.run(fullPathFolder+"/myBash")
```

Or

```
subprocess.call(fullPathFolder+"/myBash")
```

Or

```
os.system(fullPathFolder+"/myBash")

baseFolder/myPython.py

     "     myNewFolder <<<<<<<<<<?????

     "     myNewFile   <<<<<<<<<<?????

     "     folder1/myBash

     "     folder2/myBash

           .
           .
           .

      "     folderN/myBash
```

Answer (score 1):

The bash **is** executed in the folder you started you python script in. You need to change the path using `os.chdir()` before. Or better: pass the target directory as a parameter to the shell scripts and prepend the path to your file names.